# Chrome displays Flex/Flash fonts in a blur manner

Tags: google-chrome, flash, apache-flex

In the last weeks I have noticed that Chrome displays Flex/Flash fonts in a blur manner. While IE and other browsers display it well.

Chrome Example:

[image]

IE Example:

[image]

Our application is written in Flex4, did you saw this issue?

In the above screenshots the "Select Questions" label was defined with font "David"

```
<mx:Label  id="reviewLbl" fontFamily="David" fontSize="15" fontWeight="bold" color="#20809d"  x="70" y="10"/>
```

Comment: The fact that the two browsers show different fonts tells me you didn't embed your fonts. What happens if you set Arial as text font?. Also don't use HTML text since browsers render HTML text differently (but maybe it's automatic in flex?). Show an example how your code makes text. Experiment by just using a `textField` for holding text...

Comment: @VC.One I edited the question... we used regular "David" font in the Label (we also used embedded fonts, although in other places where we also seen inconsistency)

Comment: I wonder if this is because of some Chrome update (with bug)? My solution was gunna be for using `textField` but since you're using `mx:label` I hope somebody else can help you soon. I can't tell you to change all your Flex labels to AS3 textFields. Also the blurring on words "Classification" & "Difficulty" looks more like anti-aliasing (option to "soften" text so it's not rough), as an experiment make those texts slightly larger & see if the blur is still problematic (it should be a good thing for larger text).

Comment: For faster help, also update saying what version IE you're using and show how you embed the David font. Did you use CSS `@Font-face`? Or did you use `[Embed(source="David.ttf... etc`? Is your Chrome & IE using exact same Flash Player versions? (I notice the "Select Questions" font looks different and it look like your IE is using system/device fonts instead of David, which is why correct embedding is important so it does not fall-back to nearest system font)...

Comment: @VC.One I assumed some fonts are supported inherently by Flash player and does not need to be embedded (like David) maybe this was my mistake... I'll conduct some tests and update soon , thanks!

Comment: You **need** to embed David font... I don't have it installed on my computer and so I would totally see something else If I used your app. Now if embeded then it becomes part of your app (shows fine, even for users without it).